# Mobile vs non-mobile: serving appropriate content

Tags: php, mobile

I am writing a mobile version of a website, and I want to

1. use WURFL-PHP to perform the mobility check on the client.
2. re-use the existing .htaccess files.  I don't want to parse anything manually.  This is better left to Apache.

For simplicity, let's say I have two flat files: file.d.html and file.m.html.  In index.php, I consider making an appropriate HTTP request on one of these files depending on the client we are serving (mobile vs non-mobile) and forwarding the response to the client.  Everything will be the way .htaccess files prescribe.

To make the request, a PHP library called pecl_http exists.  Problem is: I only have a shared hosting plan, so my webhost is reluctant to make it available.

So, can someone tell me if this is reasonable, or I'm just complicating things?

Also, is there any way to accomplish this without an extra HTTP request?  I wonder if Apache has some way to test for mobility.  Perhaps I can add something to .htaccess instead of coding it in PHP.

Many thanks.

Comment: You can add two lines (use `include once`), in the beginning of every page, checking the user-agent and redirecting to the mobile-version if needed.

Comment: Sure. But I would really like to keep both worlds under one URL.

Comment: you could write a mod_rewrite rule to match user agents and redirect to the proper version. http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3374559.htm

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't do this server-side but with javascript and CSS media queries. Specifically there is process called '[Responsive Web Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design)' where your browser picks your styles based on the screen width in pixels. This avoids the evil of browser sniffing and therefore will generally support future mobile platforms without any changes. You can use the `display` style to hide whole blocks of content if necessary or just use different values for `width` and `float` to change from horizontal to vertical layouts. The Wikipedia page on RWD warns that some mobile platforms don't support media queries but in practice as of 2012 that's an extremely small share of the mobile market.